# Update a specific row in CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I want to update a specific row (that satisfies a pre-defined condition) in a .CSV file.

This is my code:

```
ProductID,ProductName,price,availability,type
12345,abc,300,yes,medicine
23456,def,400,yes,testing
34567,ghi,200,no,medicine
45678,jkl,500,no,testing
```

here is code

```
    CsvReader products = new CsvReader("D:\\sample.csv");
            CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\sample.csv", true), ',');
            products.readHeaders();
            products.getRawRecord();
            while (products.readRecord())
            {
                String productID = products.get("ProductID");
                String productName = products.get("ProductName");
                String supplierID = products.get("price");
                String categoryID = products.get("availability");
                String quantityPerUnit = products.get("type");

                if(productID.equals("roche123")){
                    csvOutput.replace(productName, "12", "newproductName");
                    csvOutput.replace(supplierID , "12", "newsupplierID ");
                }
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you tried so far? I think you should call some method similar to writeAll(...).

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: keeping aside you are not explaining what's the problem you have (stacktrace? undesired behaviour?), CSVReader is not a jdk class. If you are posting about an specific framework, state clearly which one in your question.

Comment: I don't think there is a replace method  on that class. Even if there was, how are you telling it which row you're replacing?

Comment: `productID.equals("roche123")` are you sure `roche123` is the product's ID and not its name? Anyway with the current code and example the answer is "because there's no line with productID "roche123".

Comment: Maybe reading and writing to the same file at the same time is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The method `CsvWriter.replace` is not an instance method and does not an inline replacement on the current record.

Rather it should be used as

```
String replace = CsvWriter.replace(
    inputString, // somefoobar
    substringToReplace, // foobar
    substringSubstitute); // candy
// replace will be "somecandy"
```

Following snippet should demonstrate the principle.

assuming `sample_in.csv` as

```
ProductID,ProductName,price,availability,type
12345,abc,300,yes,medicine
23456,def,400,yes,testing
34567,ghi,200,no,medicine
45678,jkl,500,no,testing
roche123,product 12,supplier 12,no,foobar
```

the snippet

```
CsvReader products = new CsvReader("sample_in.csv");
CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter("sample_out.csv", true), ',');
products.readHeaders();

csvOutput.writeRecord(products.getHeaders());

String[] outValues = new String[5];
while (products.readRecord()) {
    String productID = products.get("ProductID");
    String productName = products.get("ProductName");
    String supplierID = products.get("price"); // is this correct?
    String categoryID = products.get("availability");
    String quantityPerUnit = products.get("type");

    if (productID.equals("roche123")) {
        productName = CsvWriter.replace(productName, "12", "newproductName");
        supplierID = CsvWriter.replace(supplierID, "12", "newsupplierID");
    }

    outValues[0] = productID;
    outValues[1] = productName;
    outValues[2] = supplierID;
    outValues[3] = categoryID;
    outValues[4] = quantityPerUnit;
    csvOutput.writeRecord(outValues);
}
```

will produce `sample_out.csv` as

```
ProductID,ProductName,price,availability,type
12345,abc,300,yes,medicine
23456,def,400,yes,testing
34567,ghi,200,no,medicine
45678,jkl,500,no,testing
roche123,product newproductName,supplier newsupplierID,no,foobar
```

from the input line

```
roche123,product 12,supplier 12,no,foobar
```

- column `ProductName` is updated from `product 12` to `product newproductName`
- column `price` is updated from `supplier 12` to `supplier newsupplierID`

**edit** The snippet is using the [JavaCSV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) library.